# operand should contain 1 column(s) mysql error when select

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using MySql. 
when i am select multiple column from table

> responsible_id,title

then generate Error.
So I wont to select multiple column. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
 select id,
        title,
        responsible_id,
        project_id p_id,(select responsible_id,title from projects where p_id=projects.project_id) responsible_id,
        status,
        create_by,
        milestone_id from tasks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select multiple columns from a correlated subquery, this way.

`JOIN` the two tables instead, like this:

```
 select 
   t.id,
   t.title AS TaskTitle,
   t.responsible_id,
   p.project_id p_id,
   p.responsible_id,
   p.title AS ProjectTitle,
   t.status,
   t.create_by,
   t.milestone_id
from tasks AS t
INNER JOIN projects AS p ON t.p_id = p.project_id
```

Comment: I donot wont to use Join. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @GarthHuff Yes, two correlated subquery, one for responsible_id and the other for title. But why not `JOIN`??

Comment: I am using hibernate and this is not only this query but too much long query so that..